# Placing project files inder var/www rather than nginx/html

Tags: nginx, centos

I see some tutorials where people place their project files under `var/www` in linux environments as opposed to say ... the nginx default dir `usr/share/nginx/html` in many nginx related tutorials.

I would like to know if there is some benefit to putting your projects there as opposed to the default directory.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the purposes listed for the `/usr` and `/var` hierarchies in the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) should answer this question fairly well.

About [`/usr`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY):

> /usr is the second major section of the filesystem. /usr is shareable, read-only data. That means that /usr should be shareable between various FHS-compliant hosts and must not be written to. Any information that is host-specific or varies with time is stored elsewhere.

About [`/var`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY):

> /var contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.
>
> Some portions of /var are not shareable between different systems. For instance, /var/log, /var/lock, and /var/run. Other portions may be shared, notably /var/mail, /var/cache/man, /var/cache/fonts, and /var/spool/news.
>
> /var is specified here in order to make it possible to mount /usr read-only. Everything that once went into /usr that is written to during system operation (as opposed to installation and software maintenance) must be in /var.

Comment: Good answer. Then why does nginx by default create a directory, in the /usr foder?

Comment: Does nginx do that or does the package do that? Does the package install default files there and point to them from the default config? That would actually, to my mind, make some sense as a default that can then be easily over-ridden by actual configuration (as opposed to putting packaged files into `/var` or `/srv` or something which then need to be deleted to use the "natural" location).